# asp.net logging and create file every hour

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-web-api

I have a very specific requirement.

I have a .net web api, and I need to Log everything, I need to log when each api method is called, by who, time, I need to log when there are controlled and uncontrolled exceptions.

My main concern is:
1. Is this possible to do with DI? I wouldnt like to add a Logger line on the code manually everywhere.
2. How can I make the file close after 1 hour, and create a new one automatically?

Comment: I've heard Log4Net is good for things like this, I use Elmah to log exceptions and access violations but does require manually adding in a line of code to do so. To create a file every hour: create a file with a timestamp, when you need to log to it check the file name and compare the timestamp to the current time. If it's been more than an hour since it was created, create the new file with the new timestamp. You can also use tracing.

Comment: There are high performance tools such as AppDynamics as well that will log and correlate essentially everything your app does, but they are not cheap. I don't know of a tool that would "log each api method call" without manually adding logger lines for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible. I have based my answer on .Net Core but most of it (like the logger suggested and the use of middleware) applies to non .Net Core projects as well.

For starters I suggest you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging

> ASP.NET Core supports a logging API that works with a variety of logging providers. Built-in providers let you send logs to one or more destinations, and you can plug in a third-party logging framework.
>
> ASP.NET Core dependency injection (DI) provides the ILoggerFactory instance.

You can inject your logging implementation using the ILogger en ILoggerFactory interfaces.

For exception handling and access logging you can write some middleware (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware). Using middleware prevent you from having to call your logging logic in every controller action.

Something like:

```
    public class RequestTrackingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public RequestTrackingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger logger)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                [SharedProperties.TraceId] =         context.Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier,
            }))
            {
                var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                bool success = false;

                try
                {
                    await next(context);
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (System.Exception exception)
                {
                    logger.LogCritical((int)ServiceFabricEvent.Exception, exception, exception.Message);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    logger.LogRequest(context, stopwatch.Elapsed, success);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, given the link earlier there are some built-in and 3rd party logger implementations that support the provided .Net Core Logging interfaces.Pick one that has a sink (destionation) to your liking or write a sink yourself (most of the times that is not that hard based on the logger.

I have used Serilog (https://serilog.net/) since that has out-of-the-box support for .Net Core and it has many sinks. If you are not using .Net Core this is still a good pick!

**Edit:** I see Serilog supports a file based sinks that generates a new file every hour: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile

Answer (score 1):

You can use log2net. Following 2 properties will help creating log file every hour. If you have same pattern of logging on methods (ex - wrap method with log entries) then you can also you AOP (Aspect oriented programming). PostSharp is very useful in AOP.

```
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HH" />
```

ex-

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logfile" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HH" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender

https://www.postsharp.net/aspects